# Angular Mat-Accordion not working dynamically

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement the mat-accordion using dynamic data. I can console.log the data successfully so I know my service is working just fine. However, I just get a blank screen when I implement it with no errors. Any advice here? The example from the angular material website works just fine with static data. I don't think I am doing my ngFor statement correctly.

html

```
<mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let item of costCategories">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            {{item.wellName}}

        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        Description here
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

typescript

```
@Component({
  selector: 'cost-categories',
  templateUrl: './cost-categories.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cost-categories.component.scss'],
})
export class CostCategoriesComponent implements OnInit {
  panelOpenState = false;
  costCategories: ICostCategories[];
  isLoading = true

  constructor(public wellService: WellsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.wellService.getCostCategories()
      .subscribe((costCategories: ICostCategories[]) => {
        this.isLoading = false;
        (err: WellError) => console.log(err.friendlyMessage)
      });
    }
```

interface

```
export interface ICostCategories {
    wellId: string;
    wellName: string;
    afeNumber: string;
    primaryJobType: string;
}
```

Comment: Can you please share a part of ts file where you are filling the data of `costCategories`

Comment: First of All check console for errors. second, remove 'Description here' and log the costCategories to console and check if it is an array and each element has the wellName property with correct spelling or not

Comment: I don't know how are you getting the data bu have you tried this?
`*ngFor="let item of costCategories | async"`

Comment: I have updated the code with my ts file with the interface. Please note that I can successfully console.log the data and wellName is in an array.